# Create a dictionary given keys and values as lists, with duplicate keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists, `[1, 2, 2, 3]` and `[3, 4, 5, 6]`.

I want to create a dictionary, with *keys* from the first list and *values* from the second. But, because I have duplicate keys in the first list, I want to use the one with the smallest value.

So, my expected output will be:

```
{1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 6}
```

Comment: "min value or the first occurred value" This requirements contradicts itself.

Comment: And you should provide your attempted solution and what issues you faced.

Comment: What should be the expected output if the second list is `[3, 5, 4, 6]`?

Comment: what exactly is the criteria for choosing the value among duplicate keys? Is it just the minimum?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those two lists are of the same length (which I can't imagine they wouldn't be), then you could use this:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 2, 3]
l2 = [3, 4, 5, 6]

d = {}
for k, v in zip(l1, l2):
    if k not in d or v < d[k]:
        d[k] = v

print(d)
```